# Git - how do I freeze a particular version of a small file, keep it in my repository, but then ignore constant minor changes to it going forward

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a file in my source code repository that I cannot simply remove from my code base.  However, this file is constantly changing in insignificant ways.  When every I run my project in my dev environment this file gets touched, so my git repository always dutifully reports changes and asks me what to do about them.  How do I just ignore them forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Add it to your .gitignore file.](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)